# Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer/Pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword

Tags: swift

Could anyone help me with this error? I'm trying to implement the Facebook Login button for my app.

```
if var FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
        fetchProfile()
    }
}

func fetchProfile() {
    print ("fetch profile")

    let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)" ]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print (error)
            return
        }

        if let email = result["email"] as? String {
            print (email)
        }

        print (result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if var FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
```

doesn't make any sense. If `currentAccessToken()` returns a bool, it can just be

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
```

otherwise if it returns an optional, it can be

```
if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
```

or

```
if let _ = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
```

Comment: @ChrisBowser Don't forget to accept answers that best solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I was writing a Switch statement using `let foo as` like so:

```
switch (vc) {
case let vc as SomeSubclass: ()
default: ()
}
```

I ended up switching that instead to an if statement, but mindlessly copy/pasting some of the old code:

```
if let vc as SomeSubclass {

}
```

which produces the error:

> Pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword

the `if` needs to of course be changed to normal if-let form:

```
if let vc = vc as? SomeSubclass {

}
```